# User already authenticated in app and Firebase realtime database returns failed: permission_denied

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am writing to the database and trying to read it, it always says: failed: permission_denied when using the user rules from Firebase. I am trying to write and read from Firebase to write the first and last name. The tree layout is below. The user logs in on the first storyboard and the read and write are on different storyboards and view controllers.

Do I need to authenticate on the same VC as where I am trying to get the information?

I am able to generate the UserID on different VC's so I don't know what could be doing it then.

```
WRITE
ref?.child(userID).child("FirstName").setValue(firstName.text!)
```

```
READ
if let snap = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                if let firstNameResult = snap["FirstName"] as? String {
                    self.firstNameLabel.text = firstNameResult
                }else{
                    print("Error")
                }
            }else{
                print("User ID is not valid")
            }
```

```
FIREBASE RULES
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
TREE LAYOUT
IdentificationStorage
    USERID generated
        FirstName
        LastName
```

--FIX FOR READ--
Here is how the read works, the write works with just the code Ken provided below!

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users/\(userID)")
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

            guard snapshot.exists() else { return print("Invalid User ID") }
            self.firstNameLabel.text = snapshot.get("FirstName") as? String

            guard snapshot.exists() else { return print("Invalid User ID") }
            self.lastNameLabel.text = snapshot.get("LastName") as? String
        })

    }
```

Comment: Can you perhaps clean up your question a bit? It's pretty hard to read it currently with all the updates. It would be best to present it as one single "story".

Comment: Also, in your update, you don't need to `guard` against the same case twice, so you can take out the second `guard` statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rules are correct, the only issue is that when writing to your database, you need to say that the `userID` is under the `users` node. Remember to initialize your database like this:

```swift
let ref = Database.database().reference()
```

Here's your updated **WRITE** code:

```swift
ref.child("users/\(userID)/FirstName").setValue(firstName.text!)
```

Personally, I like to create an extension for `DataSnapshot` to make getting fields easier:

```swift
extension DataSnapshot {
    func get(_ field: String) -> Any? {
        return (value as? [String : Any])?[field]
    }
}
```

Just copy and paste that anywhere outside of a `ViewController`. Using this function, you can refactor your **READ** code to this:

```swift
guard snapshot.exists() else { return print("Invalid User ID") }
self.firstNameLabel.text = snapshot.get("FirstName") as? String
```

As a sidenote, it is convention for Firebase fields to be lowerCamelCase, like variables are in `Swift`.