# Swift & Firebase - Database and UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm new to Swift & Firebase and I haven't really figured it out yet. Currently I'm thinking about adding a Database to store data for the user to fetch in case he switches device.

So far I've stored data with `UserDefaults`. Now that I'll probably be using a Database, do I still need `UserDefaults`? What if the user is not able to get internet connection and closes the app, before he gets to synchronize his data going online - will there be a danger of data loss?

Or is it best to keep both - `UserDefaults` and the Database?

Comment: UserDefaults should be used for just that, the user's default settings. The things you store in UserDefaults (i.e. the value of a toggle switch that changes the color of the UI) should be different from the things you store in the database; they really shouldn't even know about each other. If the user opens the app without connection and can't connect to the database, then the user simply doesn't see the content in the database; why would there be any risk of data loss? There was no attempt to write to the database, only an attempt to read from it.

Comment: if you are using firebase as a database, there's no meaning to have the same things inside your app, in the sense that the database should have information of user A and user B, but the app should have only one user's information.

Comment: Also, think about what you would and what you wouldn't want to download from the internet in a real life situation.

Comment: I think the one question that should be asked is: what data are you storing in User Defaults and what data do you want to store in Firebase? Once we know that, a proper answer could be offered.

Answer (score 0):

A `UserDefaults` from Apple documentation:

> An interface to the user’s defaults database, where you store key-value pairs persistently across launches of your app. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults

`UserDefaults` is a great solution for keeping unique values between app sessions. For example user settings, preferences (Simple, dummy data).

To share data between 2 devices you can use Firebase Storage. Another option is a CloudKit.

Synchronisation - this is more about what you need and how you would like to handle it. You can base on online data, so there would not be need to synchronise (you are always up to date). Or make periodically synchronisation, but you would need to think about best solution for local database.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are doing. Using user defaults is certainly fine for holding defaults but not information. What if 2 people use the same device, then you have user defaults for one user and a database for the other. I personally would use just one. If you are learning Firebase I would suggest 2 tutorials:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F42CzqIBxHQ&t=406s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMudKhNY0sI&t=627s

and the question I just had answered about reading and writing to a secure database: [User already authenticated in app and Firebase realtime database returns failed: permission_denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55929743/user-already-authenticated-in-app-and-firebase-realtime-database-returns-failed)